# How to create a map data for navigation stack using kinect

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, pointcloud-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to ask that

1. how to use pointcloud_to_laserscan
2. Can rgbdslam package be used for creating a map for navigation stack?

I'd like to create a map data with kinect sensor for navigation.
I've already read some tutorials and found that
I have to use not cloud data but laser scan data.

pointcloud_to_laserscan can convert data, but
the usage is not described in the wiki.
Could you teach me how to use it?

And I found that rgbdslam can create a map using kinect.
Is this package able to generate a map for navigation stack?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37169/how-to-create-a-map-data-for-navigation-stack-using-kinect/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2012-06-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-06-25**:
Had looked at this similar question http://answers.ros.org/question/9450/how-to-setup-pointcloud_to_laserscan/

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-06-26**:
Also see this: http://answers.ros.org/question/12995/2d-map-from-octomap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RGBDSlam is the best choice if you have both the rgb and depth stream, but Depthimage_to_laserscan is better if you only have the depth data (my project is like this).
Depthimage_to_laserscan requires two things, the depth image topic and the camera_info topic (see monocular camera calibration tutorials). You'll also need to set up a coordinate frame to reference the kinect to. For example, with my stationary kinect 360, I use these:

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 map camera_depth_frame 20

rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=/kinect/mono16/image_raw camera_info:=/kinect/mono16/camera_info _scan_height:=20 _scan_time:=0.167 _range_min:=0.75 _range_max:=2.5
```

You'd probably want to use a larger scan height if possible, but my slow little raspberry pi cannot handle much more than 640x40 at 6fps, so im limited in height.

After that, you'll see a new /scan topic. Use that in place of a laser scanner as described in the navigation stack tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup

---

Originally posted by [TimboInSpace](https://answers.ros.org/users/11216/timboinspace/) with karma: 141 on 2015-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0